# Can Cochran's Q test take a 3 level nominal variable as the response (instead of 2)?

Tags: spss, repeated-measures, mcnemar-test, cochran-q

I conducted a study using  within-subjects (repeated measure) design for collecting nominal data. I have been reading a lot closet I get for a suitable test is Cochran's Q test since I have repeated measures for nominal data from the 3 related-samples. However, my responses for the dependant variables has 3 categories, and Cochran's Q test takes only 2 (e.g. yes, no)!

McNemar-Bowker Test can take 3 or more categories for the dependent variable, but it is only for 2 related samples (i.e. before and after), and I have 3 related samples.

So, is there any test similar to Cochran's Q test (3+ related samples) but taking more than 2 nominal responses for these dependent variables?

Comment: Yours is a good question, to my mind, but not yet formulated clearer. Less technically - more substantially. What do you want to test, actually? Do you want something like extension (on 3+ related samples) of McNemar-Bowker test or maybe of Cohen's kappa test (maybe with glance at a [their comparison](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/201714/3277)), or something else?

Comment: Yes, I want something like extension (on 3+ related samples) of McNemar-Bowker test

Comment: How do you define what are "symmetric cells" in a cubic table? McNemar-Bowker should test for symmetry. Perhaps what you really need is marginal homogeneity test for k related samples??

Comment: @ttnphns I want to know whether there is a significance difference between the 3+ related samples's responses on the repeated measure. Does marginal homogeneity test for k related samples differ from McNemar-Bowker test? and how can I use it please?

Comment: When the number of categories (responses) `c` is  >2, marginal homogeneity test is different from McNemar (Bowker) test. Such test for `k`=2 samples exist in Nonparametrics in SPSS. Unfortunately, for any `k`>2 it is absent in SPSS and I don't know where to seek it.

Comment: Look in here http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/K-sample-marginal-homogeneity-test-td5731806.html